# Matplotlib: Set cmap in plot_surface to x and y-axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I set the colormap in relation to the radius of the figure?

And how can I close the ends of the cylinder (on the element, not the top and bottom bases)?

My script:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from math import sin, cos, pi

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

h, w = 60,30
znew = np.random.randint(low=90, high=110, size=(60,30))
theta = np.linspace(0,2*pi, h)
Z = np.linspace(0,1,w)

Z,theta = np.meshgrid(Z, theta)

R = 1
X = (R*np.cos(theta))*znew
Y = (R*np.sin(theta))*znew


ax1 = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,linewidth = 0, cmap="coolwarm",              
vmin= 80,vmax=130, shade = True, alpha = 0.75)

fig.colorbar(ax1, shrink=0.9, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure your MCVE is complete. If your `theta` goes from 0 to 2*pi inclusive and znew doesn't depend on theta then the surface should be closed. And I don't understand your main question regarding the colormap.

Comment: The radius of the cylinder is different at each point. I would like to represent the radius at each point, so that mountains and valleys are highlighted in color.
znew is an array that contains the elevation profile and is matched to the cylinder. But the ends do not quite match.

Comment: What is this: `znew = array(60,30)`? Edit your question to make it reproducible

Comment: If your `znew` data isn't periodic in `theta` then there's no way you'll get a closed surface.

Comment: Updated script. znew now consists of random data. But you can reproduce it. I just want to color all values ​​according to their radius. In the original then arise valleys and mountains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to use the [`facecolors`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface) keyword argument of `plot_surface` to draw your surface with arbitrary (non-`Z`-based) colours. You have to pass an explicit RGBA colour four each point, which means we need to sample a colormap object with the keys given by the radius at every point. Finally, this will break the mappable property of the resulting surface, so we will have to construct the colorbar by manually telling it to use our radii for colours:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

h, w = 60,30
#znew = np.random.randint(low=90, high=110, size=(h,w))
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, h)
Z = np.linspace(0,1,w)

Z,theta = np.meshgrid(Z, theta)
znew = 100 + 10*np.cos(theta/2)*np.cos(2*Z*np.pi)

R = 1
X = (R*np.cos(theta))*znew
Y = (R*np.sin(theta))*znew
true_radius = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
norm = Normalize()
colors = norm(true_radius) # auto-adjust true radius into [0,1] for color mapping

cmap = cm.get_cmap("coolwarm")
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=0, facecolors=cmap(colors), shade=True, alpha=0.75)

# the surface is not mappable, we need to handle the colorbar manually
mappable = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
mappable.set_array(colors)
fig.colorbar(mappable, shrink=0.9, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Note that I changed the radii to something smooth for a less chaotic-looking result. The `true_radius` arary contains the actual radii in data units, which after normalization becomes `colors` (essentially `colors = (true_radius - true_radius.min())/true_radius.ptp()`).

The result:

[image: pretty result with colours as expected]

Finally, note that I generated the radii such that the cylinder doesn't close seamlessly. This mimicks your random example input. There's *nothing* you can do about this as long as the radii are not 2π-periodic in `theta`. This has nothing to do with visualization, this is geometry.